# Need help getting the area of a rectangle and a circle using a classes

Tags: c++

They need to be classes and get area needs to be part of shape, the method getArea needs to be in shape and area needs to be protected and in shape, widght height and radius part of their respective subclass (C++)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <math.h>
using namespace std;

class shape {
    protected:
        double area;
    public:
        double getArea(){return area;};
};

class rectangle:shape {
    private:
        double width;
        double height;

    public:
        rectangle(){
            width=3;
            height=4;
        }
        double getHeight(){return height;};
        double getWidth(){return width;};

        void setHeight(double h){height=h;};
        void setWidth(double w){width=w;};
        void setArea(double width, double height){area=height*width;};
};

class circle:shape {
    private:
        double radius;

    public:
        circle(){
            radius=1;
        }

        double getRadius(){return radius;};
        void setRadius(double r){radius=r;};
        void setArea(double width, double height){area=M_PI*(pow(radius,2));};
};

int main () {
    rectangle miRectangulo;
    circle miCirculo;
    cout<<"Area of the rectangle is "<<miRectangulo.getArea()<<endl;
    cout<<"Area of the circle is "<<miCirculo.getArea();

    return 0;
}
```

They do need to follow these certain conditions, right now I am getting the error that "double::shape getArea() is inaccesible"

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I understand this is an exercise designed to make you manipulate classes. It looks like you have somewhat grasped the general inheritance idea. 
To help with your specific problem we need some more details about the compilation error that you mention at the end. Could you edit your post to include the full error given by your compiler? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

By default, inheritance is private, meaning getArea isn't going to be accessible. Inherit as a public base instead.

```
class circle: public shape
{
/* snip */
};
```